# Testing if the method was called for an event in Vue

Tags: javascript, jestjs, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-multiselect

I have been trying to write a test to check if a function was called on a tag event in Vue. I have this component(a bit summed up)

```
<multiselect @tag="fn"></multiselect>

import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
export default {
    components: {
        Multiselect
    },
    name: "TagMultiselect",
    methods: {
        fn(){
            console.log("test");
        }
    }
}
```

and I am trying to test if the function **fn** is called. To do this i wrote the following test

```
it('triggers the function', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(TagMultiselect);
        const spy = jest.spyOn(TagMultiselect.methods, 'fn');
        const multiselect = wrapper.findComponent(Multiselect);
        multiselect.vm.$emit('tag');
        expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    })
```

but everytime i get

**Received number of calls: 0**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to spy the method of your component like this
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'fn');

Comment: still get Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0 unfortunately :(

Comment: try to wait the next tick before await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

Comment: ok so i tried that as well and it didn't work but then i switched to

await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate()

and it finally worked! Thank you very much!